# Query about the proof of the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals from Stoke's Theorem for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I recently studied Stoke's Theorem for differential forms on manifolds in Loring Tu's, *An Introduction to Manifolds*. As an immediate corollary he shows how this trivialises the proof for the FTLI. I have a query concerning the proof of this corollary, because I believe that Tu states something, which to him is obvious but most probably isn't fully trivial, and as I am self studying differential geometry I would like to clarify my understanding.

**Tu's Proof:** Let $C$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb R^3$ parameterized by $\textbf r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$, $a\leq t \leq b$, and $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$. a smooth scalar field. The exact formulation of the Theorem Tu proves is:
$$\int_C \nabla f\cdot d\textbf r=f(\textbf r(b))-f(\textbf r(a)).$$We take $C$ to be our manifold, and $f$ to be our $0$-form on $C$. From Stoke's Theorem
$$\int_C df =\int_{\partial C}f,$$
and it is apparent that the right hand side equals $f(\textbf r(b))-f(\textbf  r(a))$. Finally 
$$\int_C df=\int_C \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz,$$
which gives the result.

My confusion stems from the final equality. To express the exterior derivative of $f$ on $C$ in local coordinates we first need to choose some  chart on $C$, and Tu's proof suggests that he's chosen the standard chart for $\mathbb R^3$, however $C$ is clearly $1$-dimensional, so this cannot be the case. Now $C$ is actually an immersed submanifold in $\mathbb R ^3$, with inclusion map $\textbf r$ I believe (not sure though). This leads me to that believe what Tu means by the coordinates $x,y,z$ in the last equality is actually $\textbf r^*x,\textbf r^*y,\textbf r^*z$ with these $x,y,z$ the standard coordinates on $\mathbb R^3$ (Taking into account md2perpe's comment, maybe in fact Tu's co-ords should be $i^*x, i^*y, i^* z$, with $i$ the restricted identity function). This is all very fuzzy to me though, and I lack a feeling for what exactly is going on here, so any explanation about the exact nature of Tu's coordinate choice from someone more knowledgeable would be very appreciated.

*References*

*Loring Tu. An Introduction to Manifolds. Springer, 2nd edition, 2011*

Comment: $\textbf r$ is a parametrization. An inclusion map is always (I suppose) the identity map but with the immersed manifold as the domain: $\iota : C \to \mathbb R^3$, $\iota(x) = x$.

Comment: A chart on $C$ is given by the domain of the parametrization: $[a, b]$.

Comment: @md2perpe I also thought of such a chart, but struggled to reconcile it with Tu's proof.

Comment: I was wondering whether $\int_C \mathrm d\!f$ is defined as $\int_{\textbf r^{-1}(C)} \mathrm d(\textbf r^*\!f)$ or as $\int_{\textbf r^{-1}(C)} \textbf r^*\!(\mathrm d\!f)$ so I looked for the answer and found that $\mathrm d(\textbf r^*\!f) = \textbf r^*\!(\mathrm d\!f)$ so it doesn't really matter. (Theorem 4.2.1 on page 30 in https://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/diffforms.pdf)